# Uploading an image on GCP using Django REST framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload images on GCP through Postman. I am using

```
pip install google-cloud-storage
```

and my settings.py is:

```
GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET = 'bucketName' 
GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_URL = 'https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/bucketName'
GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_DEFAULT_CACHE_CONTROL = 'public, max-age: 7200'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_google_cloud_storage.GoogleCloudStorage'
```

The function for uploading image is:

```
def post(self, request):
    up_file=request.data['file']
    print('******',request.data)
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket(settings.GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET)
    d = bucket.blob(str((up_file)))
    d.upload_from_filename('C:/Users/tiwar/Downloads/'+str(up_file))
    return Response(up_file, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

but I am getting an error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte.

Comment: `str(up_file)` makes no snese, since then you aim to parse a binary file into an UTF-8 string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you please make me correct through code

Comment: What is up_file ? According the two lines on which it appears it's almost certain you do a bad usage of it.